# No scrolling on the homepage for computer and mobile/

Tags: custom-wordpress-pages

How can I make my layerslider the only thing people see on my homepage? It's a major part but there is still a background to it (I can scroll down and there is white in the background). I would like it to have zero background so people cannot scroll on the homepage.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This site is not a code-writing service and is not meant for delivering complete solutions. Users are expected to show some effort and code whilst SO is here to help you solve specific programming problems along the way. Have you tried anything already?

Comment: Yes. I've looked online for some solutions. I found this one. html,